# canonical projection of a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $R' =\mathbb{Z}_4 = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and $f = \pi$ the canonical projection of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. And let $A = 6\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=4\mathbb{Z}$.

If I've understood correctly $f$ should be an homomorphism between $R$ and $R'$.

My manual calculates $\pi(A)$ and gets a result different from mine: $\pi(A) = (A + I)/I = {I,2+I}$.

I'm applying the definition of canonical projection so $pi: A \to A/I$. For me is $\pi(A) = 6\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, I don't understand why is summing up $I$ to $A$.

Can you explain me how to calculate the image $pi(A)$ and if/why it is an ideal of R/I?

Comment: Perhaps one thing to consider is that $6\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ can only make sense if $6\mathbb{Z}$ contains $4\mathbb{Z}$.  Another one would be that if your manual defines a ring as a structure with a multiplicative unity ("$1$"), then $6\mathbb{Z}$ is not a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Take the numbers $\cdots,-12,-6,0,6,12,\cdots$ mod $4$. Notice anything?

Answer (score 1):

In general, images of ring homomorphims need not be ideals. This applies to ideals as well. For example, consider the ring homomorphism given by the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$. However, preimages of ideals are ideals.

The projection map $\pi: R \to R/I$ is given by $\pi(x) = x + I$. Then, $$\pi(A) = \{\pi(x)\;|\;x \in A\} = \{x + I\;|\;x \in A\}.$$

In the case of $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $I = 4\mathbb{Z}$ I usually refer to "$x + 4\mathbb{Z}$" as "$x$ mod $4$". We can apply the above to find $$\pi(6\mathbb{Z}) = \{x\;\text{mod}\;4\;|\;x \in 6\mathbb{Z}\}.$$

Thus, if $n \in \pi(6\mathbb{Z})$ then $n = \pi(x)$ for $x = 6 k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, $n \equiv 6k \;\text{mod}\;4$. If $k$ is even, then $k = 2l$ for some integer $l$ and $n \equiv 12l \equiv 0 \;\text{mod} \;4$ since $12 \in4 \mathbb{Z}$ and $4\mathbb{Z}$ is an ideal. Similarly, if $k$ is odd, then $n \equiv 2\; \text{mod}\;4$. This accounts for all of the possible integers $k$ so we have $\pi(6\mathbb{Z}) = \{4\mathbb{Z}, 2 + 4\mathbb{Z}\}$. Contrary to the first remark, $\pi(6\mathbb{Z})$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in \pi(6\mathbb Z)$, there is $m \in 6 \mathbb Z$ with $x = \pi(m)$, and since $m \in 6 \mathbb Z$ there is $n \in \mathbb Z$ with $m=6n$. Thus $x = \pi(6n) = 6n+4\mathbb Z = 2n+4\mathbb Z$ (recall that $a+I=b+I \iff a-b \in I$). Now:

- if $n$ is even, $n=2k$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$, and then $x = 2n+4\mathbb Z = 4k+4\mathbb Z = 0+4\mathbb Z = 4\mathbb Z$.
- if $n$ is odd, $n=2k+1$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$, and then $x = 2n+4\mathbb Z = (4k+2)+4\mathbb Z = 2+4\mathbb Z$.

Hence, $x$ is $4\mathbb Z$ or $2+4\mathbb Z$, meaning that $\pi(6\mathbb Z) = \{4\mathbb Z,2+4\mathbb Z\}$.